# Potentiometer position with op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, potentiometer

I would like to measure a 10k ohms linear potentiometer (position) with A/D converter using an op-amp like this :

[image]

In my case V+ will be 3,3 volts and Vout need to have maximum of 2,5 volts (which is my A/D converter reference). Can somebody could tell me which value are required for all resistors around the op-amp ?

Comment: It's impossible with that circuit.

Comment: Do you have any proposal ?

Answer (score 1):

If your ADC can handle source impedance of 2.5K ohms (maximum) you can directly use the pot.

The op-amp can be used as a buffer to minimize variations due to the (typically large) tolerance of the pot element.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjOroV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If it cannot handle 2.5K then you can add an op-amp voltage follower. In both cases the op-amp needs to be able to operate from 3.3V and in the second case the output needs to be able to swing near ground and the input common mode range include ground (single-supply or rail-to-rail input and output).

Comment: I think my MCU can handle 2.5 K https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/268/60001320D-967555.pdf so in that case no need Opamp if I understood, only voltage divider.

Comment: Yes, it's okay, follow the recommendations regarding sample time vs. source impedance. The op-amp shown is not needed (see @transistor's answer) but if you use it it will have much less variation due to the 10K pot tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

A series resistor is all that is needed to reduce the potentiometer maximum output voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDpHlV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A resistor will reduce the output value by the ratio \$ \frac {R_2}{R_1+R_2} \$.*

$$ \frac {2.5}{3.3} = \frac {R_2}{R_1+R_2} $$
$$ 0.76 = \frac {10k}{R_1+10k} $$
$$ 0.76 R_1 + 7.6k = 10k $$
$$ R_1 = \frac {10k - 7.6k}{0.76} = 3.15\ \text k \Omega $$

There is no need for the op-amp.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQR4bg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I would use elements of the other two answers in the following way. In the schematic R2 is the potentiometer. R1 reduces the 3.3V to 2.49V. The opamp buffer produces a low source impedance to the ADC. Use a rail-rail opamp.

Comment: Great, is the MCP6021 is ok ?

Comment: Most any rail-rail (input & output) opamp will work here.  MCP6021 works. Do you really need the 10 MHz bandwidth? MCP6271 is nice.